# Passing file from jQuery Ajax method to Webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, file, web

I've a file upload control in my .aspx page. that file upload only allows excel files. after correct file is posted in that control. I'm rendering  that control via JavaScript and passing that file to Web service, which has a method to access and do some calculation  on that file.
I read some article for that. there is no such a functionality exist to transfer file via client side. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTML5 [File upload](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/7/30/html5-powered-ajax-file-uploads), but only FF, chrome and Safari support these functions.

What you can do is using HTML5 upload with Flash or iFrame post as backup. 
A plugin with all browser support for jQuery can be found [here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Comment: Thanks Niels. I will try that. I used iFrame for an instance. but that page layout changed unexpectedly.